# How do you get the available bounds inside a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, user-interface

When using a UITabBarController, how do you get the size of the tab bar at the bottom  ?Similarly, how do you know how much room you have inside the tabbed-view for your content? I see a lot of examples of people sizing their tab child views to [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame], which can’t be correct because the tab bar takes up some room at the bottom of the screen.

Also, is it possible to modify the size of the tab bar?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can use applicationFrame is that UITabBarController resizes its subcontrollers' views, so as long as your view supports resizing correctly, it'll all work out.

You can get the size of the tab bar by accessing your tab bar controller's tabBar property and looking at its frame.  The total size of the tab bar plus the area for the view can be found by looking at the tab bar controller's view property's frame, so a little subtraction will get you the number you're looking for:

```
CGFloat myViewHeight = tabBarController.view  .size.height
                     - tabBarController.tabBar.size.height;
```

Comment: What sdk version are you using? I am using 2.2.1, and I can't access the tabBar property

Comment: .size is not a property of tabBar

Comment: @ChrisP You're absolutely right--you'd need `.frame.size`, not `.size`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Just a small addition. Instead of working with the [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] you can initialize your root view with anything you like, e.g. self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; Due to the resizing you only have to have your autoresizingMask correct.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but anyway:

If you do not load your view from a NIB, set the auto resizing flags in your loadView func; something like this:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

If you do so, you can use [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] to specify your view's frame; it will be resized automatically if a tab bar is present.

If you have a NIB for your view, the autoresizingMask is set automatically by Interface Builder.

Markus

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed! My code is `UITableView* table = [[UITableView alloc] initWIthFrame: self.view.bounds style: UITableViewStylePlain]; table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizignFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` in a subclass of UIViewController, viewDidLoad method. The `initWithFrame: self.view.bounds` is useless though, I just set that as the "initial size" (which gets resized/replaced immediately). Markus' solution also supports rotation autoresizing. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out how to resize a UITabBar, then you can resize a UITabBarController's UITabBar.  You can access the object by taking

```
[[UITabBarController subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
```

But it's recommended in the documentation that you don't directly access the object.